# Communication between preferences.xul and preferences.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, add-on

I was wondering if any one was familiar with a best practice when writing firefox extensions, regarding the communication between preferences.xul and preferences.js.

For example, if you have a tree view in preferences.xul, and you want to load it full of data programatically from preferences.js, how could you access the tree object. Would it be some thing like "gBrowser.getElementById..."?

I tried assigning a variable to the tree node, via "onload='var cks_tree = this'" but it seems that the tree is loaded AFTER the preferences.js, so, i'm gonna have to access it some other way...

Just to be clear, because i just found a similar question, this question involves 2 separate files - not an XUL file with a script in it, but an XUL file and a javascript file.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have tree in XUL file, you should put the script tag at the end of xul file (just before the closing tag of document element).